# php resize & crop image only if exceeding certain pixel size

Tags: php, image, resize, scale

I have a script that scale an image on server and save onto itself, which is fine, but I like to modify it so this script applies only if the original image exceeds certain pixel size and crop the result finally,

so the flow is
1. if source image is higher than 80 pixel or wider than 300 pixel then continue
2. scale the source image proportionally to 80 pixel high
3. if the new width is over 300 pixel then crop the image to 300 pixels starting from left edge
4. save the image onto itself

the php I used for scaling is

```
<?php
$org_info = getimagesize("test.jpg");
$rsr_org = imagecreatefromjpeg("test.jpg");
$rsr_scl = imagescale($rsr_org, 320, 80,  IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED);
imagejpeg($rsr_scl, "test.jpg");
imagedestroy($rsr_org);
imagedestroy($rsr_scl);
?>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use getimagesize (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get image size in php.

And imagecopyresized to resize image with new dimensions (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecopyresized.php).

```
$size = getimagesize($filename);
// $size[0] is width
// $size[1] is height

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
```